# Why is the component of a differentiable function also differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, self-learning

I'm self studying with the Spivak book, and I'm trying to see a result that I know to be true but I'm having some time seeing how the maths pans out.  Supposing a function $f$ is differentiable.  Then given the projection operator $\pi^i$ where $\pi^i(f)=f^i$, $f^i$ must also be differentiable.

I've been trying to work it out by applying the chain rule
$$Df^i(a)=D(\pi^i\circ f)(a)=D\pi^i(f(a))\circ Df(a)$$
since the projection operator is linear, it's derivative is simply itself
$$Df^i(a)=\pi^i(f(a))\circ Df(a)$$
$$Df^i(a)=f^i(a)\circ Df(a)$$
I'm fairly sure the steps leading up to this point are correct, however it doesn't seem to make sense.  For example, let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$
$$f=\begin{bmatrix}x^2\\x\end{bmatrix}$$
then
$$Df=\begin{bmatrix}2x\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
So if we let $i=1$,
$$\begin{align}
Df^1(a)&=f^1(a)\circ Df(a) \\
&=a^2\circ\begin{bmatrix}2a\\1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$
Which I am certain is wrong, since $Df:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, but $f^1:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ so it doesn't match up.  I think I have misunderstood either the derivative of the projection operator or how $f^i(a)$ forms a composition with $Df(a)$.  Could someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing some notation, and probably misunderstanding what it means to say "derivative of a linear transformtion at every point is itself". In the beginning you write $\pi^i(f)=f^i$. This is not at all what Spivak writes. $\pi^i$ is a function $\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$, so its input is a tuple of numbers $(a^1,\dots, a^n)$ and its output is $a^i$. By definition if we have a function $f:\Bbb{R}^k\to\Bbb{R}^n$, then by $f^i$, we mean the function $\pi^i\circ f$. Now,
\begin{align}
(Df^i)(a)&=D(\pi^i\circ f)(a)=(D\pi^i)(f(a))\circ Df(a)=\pi^i\circ Df(a),
\end{align}
where the last equality is because $\pi^i:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ is a linear transformation, so at any point (for example $f(a)$) its derivative is itself. This equality makes sense, because $f^i:\Bbb{R}^k\to\Bbb{R}$, so $Df^i(a):\Bbb{R}^k\to\Bbb{R}$ is linear. On the RHS we have a composition $Df(a):\Bbb{R}^k\to\Bbb{R}^n$ with $\pi^i:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$.

For your example below, Spivak uses the $D$ notation to mean the linear transformation and the prime notation to refer to the corresponding matrix representations relative to the standard bases. So, if $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^2$ is given as $f(x)=(x^2,x)$, then $Df(a):\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^2$ is the linear transformation
\begin{align}
Df(x)[h]&=(2xh,h)
\end{align}
And so $Df^1(a)[h]=(\pi^1\circ Df(a))[h]=\pi^1(2ah,h)=2ah$.

Or if you prefer matrices, then
\begin{align}
(f^1)'(a)&=(\pi^1)'(f(a))\cdot f'(a)\\
&=[\pi^1]_{\text{standard bases}}\cdot f'(a)\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
2a\\
1
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=2a,
\end{align}
where $[\pi^1]$ is the matrix representation of the linear map $\pi^1$ with respect to the standard basis $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ on the domain $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\{1\}$ on the target space $\Bbb{R}$. This should of course make sense because $f^1(x)=(\pi^1\circ f)(x)=\pi^1(x^2,x)=x^2$, so the derivative at a point $a$ is $2a$.

Comment: I have a few questions

1.  When Spivak writes "$\pi^i(x)=x^i$" does that mean that it only applies to tuples of numbers?  So if I have a function $f=(f^1,\cdots,f^n)$ then $\pi^i(f)$ is just not defined?

2.  Doesn't $(D\pi^i)_{f(a)}$ have to be $f(a)$ "substituted into" $D\pi^i$?  For example if it's $f=(x^2+a)^2$ the corresponding term would be the $2(x^2+a)$ term.  It seems to me that the $f(a)$ has simply vanished?

Comment: @Redcrazyguy of course, $\pi^i$ is defined only on tuples of numbers, so $\pi^i(x)=\pi^i(x^1,\dots, x^n)=x^i$ for $x=(x^1,\dots, x^n)\in\Bbb{R}^n$. $\pi^i(f)$ just makes no sense in this scenario. Of course, one can define a new object $P^i:(\text{functions $\Bbb{R}^k\to\Bbb{R}^n$})\to(\text{functions $\Bbb{R}^k\to\Bbb{R}$})$ defined as $P^i(f)=\pi^i\circ f$, but why bother with this extra layer of obscurity.

Comment: Next, $(D\pi^i)_{f(a)}$ means the derivative of the function $\pi^i$ at the point $f(a)$. Look at Spivak's theorem 2-3(2). We have $D(\text{linear transformation})_{\text{any point in the domain}}=\text{that same linear transformation}$. THis equal sign is one of linear transformations. So here, $(D\pi^i)_{f(a)}=\pi^i$, for ANY function $f$ mapping into the domain of $\pi^i$, and ANY point $a$ in the domain of $f$, simply because $\pi^i$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: But be careful, this is a very special (but important) result, and it's only true for linear transformations! Seems like you need to spend some time appreciating that $D(\text{function})_{\text{point}}$ is a linear transformation and that $(\text{function})'(\text{point})$ is a corresponding matrix. You need to understand what type of object each is, and how they relate to each other (which is basic linear algebra). Otherwise, alot of what Spivak says afterwards will become confusing.

Comment: I think I understand the first part, but I want to check that I'm understanding the second part.  Basically, we have a linear function $Df(h)$ called the derivative which we use to approximate $f$.  We can evaluate this at a point $a$, denoted by $Df_a(h)$ which would be an approximation for points near $a$.  However this would not be a function of $x$, but of the "small step" $h$ used in the approximation.  If the mapping from domain to range is linear, we can use the same mapping to approximate it, i.e. the differential

Comment: so when we have some function like $y=ax$ the mapping is multiplying by $a$, which is the derivative and which can be used to approximate the points near $x$.  How this applies is when we say $D\pi^i(f(a))$ what we are really saying is $D\pi^i$ evaluated at $f(a)$, which (because it is linear) is just $\pi^i$.  Therefore, in the chain rule the mapping is just $D\pi^i(f(a))\rightarrow \pi^i$

Comment: Wait I'm a bit confused then about the matrix representation, because when you write $(\pi^i)'(f(a))$ wouldn't this be the mapping $\pi^i$ taking an input of $f(a)$?

Comment: @Redcrazyguy take a look at my answer again. I have modified the notation to correspond exactly with what Spivak writes (what Spivak writes $Df(a)$, I have originally written as $Df_a$ simply because it is easier to read. because if I want to evaluate on a "displacement" $h$ then $Df_a(h)$ is much easier to read than $Df(a)[h]$ and of course, $D(g\circ f)_a=Dg_{f(a)}\circ Df_a$ is much easier to read than $Dg(f(a))\circ Df(a)$).

Comment: @Redcrazyguy so yes $D\pi^i(f(a))=\pi^i$. This is an actual equal sign (not an arrow $\to$ as you write) asserting the equality of two linear transformations (which again, I previously wrote as $(D\pi^i)_{f(a)}=\pi^i$ simply because I think it's easier to read). Apologies for the mixup in notation.

Comment: I have a quick follow up on the notation, but I just re-read the proof and Spivak uses $f^i=\pi^i\circ f$.  Is the "evaluated at a" basically implied here?

Comment: @Redcrazyguy  which page/sentence are you referring to? I mean $f^i=\pi^i\circ f$ is obvious/true by definition.

Comment: p.21 (3), sorry I checked what I wrote again and it is different, no problem.

Comment: so $f^i=\pi^i\circ f$ is obvious. $\pi^i$ is linear so it is differentiable at $f(a)$ and $f$ is differentiable at $a$ by assumption, so $f^i$ is differentiable at $a$ by the chain rule, with $Df^i(a)=D\pi^i(f(a))\circ Df(a)=\pi^i\circ Df(a)$.